# Lipschitz function where $f ^2$ is not Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis

I found this problem when going through Lipschitz functions, I wanted to solve it but could not come up with any such function. Help is appreciated.

> Give an example of a Lipschitz function $f$ on $[0,∞)$ such that its square $f^2$ is not a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x$ :)

Comment: @orange simple as that? really?

Comment: I believe, Ii the domain of $f$ is bounded and $f$ is Lipshitz, then so $f^2.$ So counterexamples will have to be be on and unbounded domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x$. $g(x)=x^2$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: are you sure about f(x) = x? it says $[0, ∞]$

Comment: Your question says $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @TigranMinasyan $x \mapsto x$ is Lipschitz everywhere, because $|x-y| \leq |x-y|$ for all $x,y$...

Comment: And $x^2$ is not because $|(x+1)^2-x^2|=2x+1$ is not  bounded.